# What words should I use to describe the whole fashion outfit?

Tags: word-choice

My sister wants to create her own fashion brand in Russia. This brand contains a simple English word, no names or last names at all. She asked me how she should express the idea of the whole outfit, set of clothing, I mean, fashion look created by this brand. Her friend having her own brand uses the phrase "total look by /brandname/". But her friend's brand name contains a name and a last name of a person, while my sister's one doesn't. I doubt if the expression "total look" is really correct in this case and I would like to ask how to express the idea of the whole outfit created by my sister's brand. Like, we have a photo of a model dressed in this outfit, and how should she say in this case?

Comment: "by " may be followed by a brand name, e.g. "... by Coca-Cola" or "sportswear by Nike".

Answer (score 2):

***ensemble***, from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ensemble):

> Clothing & Fashion) a person's complete costume; outfit
>
> the entire costume of an individual, esp. when all the parts are in
>   harmony

If your sister is coordinating everything that the person is wearing from head to toe and everything in between (including jewelry and other accessories) she is creating *ensembles*.  This doesn't mean that everything matches, but that everything goes well together.

Comment: Wow, I used to consider ensemble as a French word. Thank you so much. So, 'ensemble by /brandname/' will do?

Comment: "Ensemble by [your sister's name]" would do, and would sound chic.

Comment: She absolutely wants the brand name to be included, not her own name.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your sister's name was the brand name.  "Ensemble by [brandname] is fine.

Comment: Got it. And this 'total look' wouldn't sound good, right?

Comment: "total look" is also fine.  Some brand names might sound better with "ensemble" and some brand names might sound better with "total look".  For example, suppose the brand name was Exotica, then "Ensemble by Exotica" would sound better than "Total Look by Exotica".   But "Total Look by Temptation" sounds better (to me) than "Ensemble by Temptation."